# Обращение к элементам массива при использовании operator new[](size_t _Size)

Tags: c++

Начал разбираться с placement new и столкнулся с непонятным для меня поведением.
Допустим у меня есть простой класс (код исключительно тестовый)

```
{
public:
  TestClass() : a(1) {}
  TestClass(int in) : a(in) {}
  ~TestClass() {}
  void SetA(int in) { a = in; }
  int GetA() { return a; }

private:
  int a;
};
```

далее создаю два массива разными способами

```
  TestClass * arr1 = new TestClass[2];
  arr1[0].SetA(1);
  arr1[1].SetA(2);
```

```
  void * arrPtr = ::operator new[](sizeof(TestClass) * 2);
  TestClass * arr2 = new (arrPtr) TestClass(10);
  new (static_cast<TestClass*>(arrPtr) + sizeof(TestClass)) TestClass(20);
```

при обращении к элементам первого массива проблем не возникает

```
  std::cout << arr1[0].GetA() << std::endl;
  std::cout << arr1[1].GetA() << std::endl;

результат:
1
2
```

но при аналогичном обращении ко второму массиву резульат следующий

```
  std::cout << arr2[0].GetA() << std::endl;
  std::cout << arr2[1].GetA() << std::endl;
  std::cout << arr2[4].GetA() << std::endl;

результат:
10
-842150451
20
```

то есть смещение происходит не на размер класса, а на один байт, хотя типы указателей одинаковые.
Объясните, пожалуйста, по какой причине так происходит (желательно максимально подробно)?

P.s. Использовал visual studio 17

Comment: *"смещение происходит не на размер класса, а на один байт"* Вовсе нет. Это вот здесь слишком большое смещение: `static_cast<TestClass*>(arrPtr) + sizeof(TestClass)`, вместо `+ sizeof(...)` должно быть `+ 1`. Закрываем как опечатку?

Answer (score 3):

Почему здесь

```
static_cast<TestClass*>(arrPtr) + sizeof(TestClass)
```

вы вдруг прибавляете `sizeof(TestClass)`???

Следующий элемент массива - это просто

```
static_cast<TestClass*>(arrPtr) + 1
```

> смещение происходит не на размер класса, а на один байт,

Не ясно, про какой "один байт" вы ведете речь. Смещение в вашем варианте происходит на `sizeof(TestClass) * sizeof(TestClass)` байт.

Comment: Я думаю, что следует немного уточнить про арифметику указателей в целом.

Comment: @MrBin, думаю, что не следует. Это должны знать все.